# What happens to new in class constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

This is my class definition and only copy constructor from a larger program.  When my destructor executes, will it automatically release the 'coeff' memory?  I believe that it does, however, my program throws a _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData) error after the program  has been completed.

```
class Poly
{
private:
int order; //order of the polynomial
int size; //order + 1
int * coeff;//pointer to array of coeff on the heap

public:
Poly();
Poly(int Order);
Poly(int Order, int * Coeff);
~Poly(){cout << "Destructor\n";};
Poly(const Poly &rhs);

//accessors &  mutators
void set();
void set(int * Coeff, int Order);
int getorder(){return order;};
int * get()const{return coeff;};

//Overloaded Operators
Poly operator+(const Poly &rhs);
Poly operator-(const Poly &rhs);
Poly operator*(const int scale);
Poly operator=(const Poly &rhs);
Poly operator*(const Poly &rhs);
const int& operator[](int I)const;
int& operator[](int I);
bool operator==(const Poly &rhs);
int operator( )(int X);
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & Out, const Poly &rhs);
friend istream & operator >>(istream & In, Poly &rhs);
};

Poly::Poly(const Poly &rhs)
{
order = rhs.order;
size = rhs.size;
int *coeff = new int[size];
for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
    coeff[i] = rhs.coeff[i];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: No, your destructor doesn't release anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructor will do as your code, nothing more. Your destructor just prints a message. Try below code:

```
~Poly() {
    delete [] coeff; // if you allocated memory by new in constructor!
}
```

As a hint, try not to use bare pointers. There are always `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`,...

Comment: I tried doing that as well and the new error is 'crt detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer'.  I'm guessing that I might be using too many 'new' statements.  Unfortunately we're not allowed to use any STL (i.e. vectors, etc.).  My program works, which is the good thing.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor will only `cout << "Destructor\n"`. It will not release any memory.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor takes care of any memory that the constructor allocated automatically, it won't do anything more. So if you allocated memory by yourself (like when you used `new`), the destructor will leave it. If it would behave differently, it could destroy data you're using in a different place of the program. That's why it doesn't do `delete` on variables you created with `new` or `new[]`.

Check your IDE documentation hovewer, because it can have a cleanup mechanism that clears all data after the program shuts, and it can embed that mechanism automatically in your output code.